# Problems connecting to mysql database using mysql1 package on flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

im tying to connect to my mysql database using mysql1 package, i've tried sqljocky as well, but both of them dont work.
I get error Error: Unsupported operation: RawSocket constructor
my code is exactly like in example, heres my code, maybe youll see what im doing wrong.

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Database {

  static var s = ConnectionSettings(
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    host: "host",
    port: 3306,
    db: "db",
  );

static Future<MySqlConnection> connect() async{
  return await MySqlConnection.connect(s);

}}
```

Comment: Does your code work on the Android emulator? I get a similar message when I use the web browser to access mysql but it works fine on Android. I think for host you should used either 'local host' or '10.0.2.2' for emulator

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, mysql1 does not support web: https://github.com/adamlofts/mysql1_dart#flutter-web

I think in general, a web application would be better off using a REST-API approach, since you don't want to expose your SQL credentials in the Frontend.